# Batch Programming: Why is my choice system not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch game and it works until you go to answer the first question (choice1Scene1)

```
@echo off
title RPG
color 0C

:top

echo ***************************************************************************

echo                     ~Welcome To Wild West Ranger~

echo ***************************************************************************

echo.

echo.

echo                  please type answers exactly as they appear

echo.

echo.

echo                     ~Enter S To Begin Your New Life~

echo.

echo.

echo.

set /p opt=

if %opt%==S GOTO name

if %opt%!==!S GOTO top

if %opt%==s GOTO name

if %opt%!==!s GOTO top



pause

cls



:name

echo ***************************************************************************

echo                        What Will You Be Called?

echo ***************************************************************************



set /p playerName=

set playerHealth=100HP

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo.



cls



echo Your name is %playerName%?

echo Key:

echo [1] Yes

echo [2] Redo

echo [e] Exit

echo.



set /p playerNameChoice=

if %playerNameChoice%==1 goto nameConfirmed

if %playerNameChoice%==2 goto name

if %playerNameChoice%==e goto exit



:nameConfirmed

echo WELCOME %playerName% TO THE WEST


echo.

echo.

cls

goto gameStart











:gameStart

echo.

echo [Health %playerHealth%]

echo You wake up on the ground outside an old wooden barn...

echo What will you do?

echo.

echo.



echo [1] Get up and walk inside the barn

echo [2] Get up and look for others

echo [3] Go back to sleep





set /p %playerChoice1Scene1%=





if %playerChoice1Scene1%==1 goto choice1'2Scene1

if %playerChoice1Scene1%==2 goto choice2Scene1

if %playerChoice1Scene1%==3 goto choice1Scene1

if %playerChoice1Scene1%!==!1 goto gameStart

if %playerChoice1Scene1%!==!2 goto gameStart

if %playerChoice1Scene1%!==!3 goto gameStart













:choice1'2Scene1

echo.

echo [Health %playerHealth%]

echo You walk around around the barn and enter through two big wooden doors.

echo Inside you see a table with two choice weapons on it...

echo.

echo.



echo [Spanish Pistol] Fast Fire, 15 Bullets, Not As Accurate

echo [Long-Barreled Western Pistol] Medium Fire, 10 Bullets, Very Accurate



set /p %playerChoice1Scene1%=



if %playerChoice1Scene1%==Spanish Pistol goto choice1'3Scene1

if %playerChoice1Scene1%==Long-Barreled Western Pistol goto choice1'3Scene1

if %playerChoice1Scene1%!==!Spanish Pistol goto choice1'2Scene1

if %playerChoice1'2Scene1%!==!Long-Barreled Western Pistol goto choice1'2Scene1









:exit
cls
echo ***************************************************************************
echo.
echo                 Thanks For Playing Wild West Ranger
echo.
echo ***************************************************************************
pause
exit
```

Comment: Consider reading the help file for a command before you ask questions. At a command prompt you can type the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. example: `if /?`

Answer (score 0):

`set /p %playerChoice1Scene1%=` attempt to set *thecurrentcontentsof*playerChoice1Scene1. Remove the `%`s to set the *variable* `playerChoice1Scene1`

and please post only that part of the code that is necessary to show your problem, along with a description of what the code is supposed to do and what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Magoo says, what's with the `!==!` symbols? There's no such operator. You need `if "%opt%" NEQ "S"`, or `if not "%opt%" == "S". For case-insensitive tests,`if /i`. Type`if /?` for help.

Secondly, the `choice` command is easier to use for your purpose. Type `choice /?` for help.